# Dividing fraction doesn't give decimals

Tags: java, string, division, fractions

I'm trying to divide a fraction but it doesn't give the asked result.

For example:

My code:

```
    int numerator = 1;
    int denominator = 2;

    String s;
    double product = numerator / denominator;
    s = numerator + "/" + denominator + "(" + product + ")";
    System.out.println(s);
```

The result is 1/2(0.0) and it should be 1/2(0.5)

Is it maybe because i am using a double or is it a bad rounding?

Comment: int / int -> cast one of these to double -> int / double or double / int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division of an `int` by an `int` gives an `int`. So, you need one of them to be floating point to get answer in floating points.

Simply, you can do:

```
double product = numerator / (denominator * 1.0);
```

or

```
double product = numerator / (double) denominator;
```

or

```
double product = (double) numerator / denominator;
```